# Deploying QML external module to IOS

Tags: ios, qt, qml, qt5.5

I'm trying to deploy a QML application to IOS, the problem is that this app depend on a external QML module.
I added the module path to the QML2_IMPORT_PATH, and it works fine when I run it in the desktop I'm developing on, the problem happens when I try to deploy to IOS, in that case I keep getting the error message:

> "module ModuleName is not installed"

I'd this problem before and "solved" it copying the whole module tree to the project directory, but it's not a good solution and I want to understand why this is happening.
So, I tried only adding the module directory to the QML project (without copying the files), but the error is still there, I even tried to add it as resource files.

My guess is that I'm missing some step in the deployment process to be able to deploy the module with my app, but can't find any information regarding this.
Any idea?

Qt version: 5.5 Indie Mobile License

Qt Creator 3.4.2

IOS: 8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy to IOS everything must be in the same bundle, including the modules.

So to solve that I'd to add all files I needed in the resource file system of the project.
After that I'd to include the qrc module path in the import path:

```
engine.addImportPath("qrc:/modules/");
```

Now everything is working as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

I looked a lot for a similar issue and some examples.

So, for anyone reaching this page:

- read/follow this https://forum.qt.io/topic/56878/qml-plugin-on-ios/6
- example code for with Qt 6.3.1: https://gitlab.com/q-quark/qt-example-plugin-subdirs

Original code and work by Tim Day (see on the forum link above)